# How to make the ionic radio toggle on/off?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I want the user to be able to toggle one option. If they toggle to another option within a section, it will toggle the other previously made selection to off. A user will also be able to deselect their selection (i.e).
Steps:-

1. Tap button 1(button 1 turns "off" to "on")
2. Tap button 1 again(it should turn "On" to "Off")

I used the following code

```
    app.directive('kmItoggleRadio', function() {
  return{
    restrict:'E',
    compile: function(element,attrs) 
    {
      var leftTitle='';
            if(angular.isUndefined(attrs.kmLeftTitle)) {
               leftTitle='';
            }
            else {
                leftTitle=attrs.kmLeftTitle;
            }
      var rightTitle='';
            if(angular.isUndefined(attrs.kmRightTitle)) {
               rightTitle='';
            }
            else {
                rightTitle="  "+attrs.kmRightTitle ;
            }
      var show='false';
            if(angular.isUndefined(attrs.kmShow)) {
              show="true";
            }
            else {
              show=attrs.kmShow;
            }

      var htmlText='<div><div ng-switch on="format">'+
            '<div ng-switch-when="kmForm">'+
            '<div ng-show='+show+'>'+
            '<ul class="list">'+
            '<li class="item item-toggle">'+
            ''+leftTitle+''+
            '<label class="toggle toggle-positive">'+
            '<input type="radio" value="'+attrs.kmValue+'" ng-model="'+attrs.kmModel+'" >'+
            '<div class="track">'+
            '<div class="handle"></div>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</label>'+
            '</ul>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
            '<div ng-switch-when="kmPreview">'+
            '<div ng-show='+show+'>'+
            '<ul class="list">'+
            '<li class="item item-toggle">'+
            ''+leftTitle+''+
            '<label class="toggle toggle-positive">'+
            '<input type="checkbox" disabled="true" value="'+attrs.kmValue+'" ng-model="'+attrs.kmModel+'">'+
            '<div class="track">'+
            '<div class="handle"></div>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</label>'+
            '</ul>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div></div>';
            element.replaceWith(htmlText);
    }
  }
})
```

In HTML

```
<km-itoggle-radio  km-model="a.c" km-value="d" km-left-title="Dhoni"></km-itoggle-radio>
<km-itoggle-radio  km-model="a.c" km-value="s" km-left-title="Kohli"></km-itoggle-radio>
```

I want to know how to make the radio button toggle on/off by tapping the button again (with out tapping the other button in same group).

Answer (score 3):

Why not use the built in `ion-toggle`?

[Ionic toggle Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/tfAzj)

```
     <ion-toggle ng-repeat="item in settingsList"
                ng-model="item.checked" 
                ng-checked="item.checked">
             {{ item.text }}
    </ion-toggle>
```

Comment: i know this and i implemented it too. but let say i have 2 checkbox A,B. If i tap A , A should go "On" and B should go "Off". I need to use checkbox and not radio button

Comment: @mhartington- Checkbox or radio button anything is fine

Comment: And how do you add these toggle controls to a group so that only one may be checked at a time?